# dynamic query error in ibatis

Tags: sql, ibatis, dynamic-sql

I got an error with a dynamic query.  This is the query that i have:

```
<dynamic>
    select * from Tbl_Member
    WHERE

    <isNotNull property="FirstName">
      FIRST_NAME = #lastName#
    </isNotNull>

    <isNotNull prepend="and" property="lastName">
      LAST_NAME = #lastName#
    </isNotNull>

    <isNotNull prepend="and" property="">

    </isNotNull>

     .
     .
     .
     .

</dynamic>
```

If the property `FirstName` is not null, the query works.  But if the property is null and the other left property `LastName` is not null, I get a SQL error.

Because in this condition the SQL statement becomes as follow:

```
  select * from Tbl_Member WHERE AND LAST_NAME = ? ...
```

How can I remove the first-prepended `AND` if the first property becomes `Null`

P.S:

I also tried `removeFirstPrepend="true"`

```
<isNotNull prepend="and" property="lastName" removeFirstPrepend="true">
  LAST_NAME = #lastName#
</isNotNull>
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with

```
<dynamic prepend="WHERE">
```

---

```
select * from Tbl_Member
<dynamic prepend="WHERE">

<isNotNull prepend="and" property="FirstName">
  FIRST_NAME = #lastName#
</isNotNull>

<isNotNull prepend="and" property="lastName">
  LAST_NAME = #lastName#
</isNotNull>

<isNotNull prepend="and" property="">

</isNotNull>

 .
 .
 .
 .

</dynamic>
```

http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s09.html